# Tap UINavigationBar title to change

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I was wondering how I could create a Navigation Bar where the user could tap the title of the navigation bar, so that it will open a new modal view, similar to the Twitter application when the user is creating a Tweet when they have multiple accounts linked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put a custom subclass of `UIView` as the `titleView` of the navigation bar. The easiest thing is to make this a button (or a `UIButton` on a `UIView`) and set up an action to present the modal view as you like. You could instead set a view to respond to touches, but I really don't see the advantage of going that route.